# Trying to pull the Last updated row_id from source table to another table after each insert into the destination table in MySQL 5.6 using a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi I have two tables Experiment and Sample.
I want to create a trigger such that whenever I insert a row into Sample table it should pull the recent 'Experiment_id' that is generated by MySQL in the 'Experiment' table and pull into a column of 'Sample' table named 'Experiment_id'.

```
EXPERIMENT TABLE
Experiment_id(auto_incremented)  Exp_name
1                                  abc

SAMPLE TABLE
Sample_id   Experiment_id sample_name
1              1                    
2              1           
3              1                    
4              1           
5              1           
6              1

**New Entry Exp name - xyz**

EXPERIMENT TABLE
Experiment_id(auto_incremented)  Exp_name
1                                  abc
2                                  xyz

SAMPLE TABLE
Sample_id   Experiment_id sample_name
1              1                    
2              1           
3              1                    
4              1           
5              1           
6              1
7              2           
8              2          
9              2                    
10             2
```

So Sample id '1-6' is generated when there is only 'Experiment_id' 1 is existing in the 'Experiment' table and Sample_ id '7-10' is generated when experiment_id 2 is auto generated by MySQL.

I am using mysql 5.6. Please someone help me, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a trigger for that. Just use a subquery in the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (sample_name, Experiment_id) VALUES (
  'sample name',
  (SELECT MAX(Experiment_id) FROM EXPERIMENT)
)
```

If you want to do it with a trigger, try this:

```
create trigger SAMPLE_before_insert before insert on SAMPLE FOR EACH ROW 
  set new.Experiment_id = (select max(Experiment_id) from EXPERIMENT);
```

Comment: I could do that but I want it to be automated as I will be using it to import data using excel

Comment: And what exactly is the problem to use the same with data from "excel"? Or what does "import data using excel" mean?

Comment: I will be using MySQL Workbench to import the data through import data wizard

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use both trigger to track insert and update:

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_experiment_after_insert;
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_experiment_after_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON experiment FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    -- sample_id will be auto_increment
    INSERT INTO sample_log SET experiment_id = NEW.experiment_id;
  END; $$

  DELIMITER ;
```

Use update trigger to track update:

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_experiment_after_update;
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_experiment_after_update
  AFTER UPDATE ON experiment FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    -- sample_id will be auto_increment
    INSERT INTO sample_log SET experiment_id = OLD.experiment_id;
  END; $$

  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi Rakib, thanks for the quick response but it worked for only a single line.To be precise the 'Experiment_id' generated at the Experiment table was '300', so when I tried to enter value at the Sample table 'Experiment_id' for row 1 showed up to be '300' but the next entry showed 'NULL'

Comment: Yes, if you want to track each insert then it will work. But if you want to track each update then you have to create update trigger. You wrote in the question to track insert. Do you want to track each update?

Comment: Yes, that would be great! Sorry for the wrong interpretation of the question.

Comment: The update trigger is generating '0'in the "Experiment_id" of Sample table for after first row entry

Comment: Updated the `update` trigger, use `OLD` instead if `NEW`

Comment: Thanks Rakib, this worked as well for me and I have given an up vote to your answer but its just not showing up because I have less than 15 points.

Comment: Ahh It's okay :) no worries. Probably you have made some changes in the question later which I saw after few hours.